# How to rsync a large binary file between two macOS distant machines

Tags: macos, ssh, backup, rsync

I'm trying to sync a large binary file between a remove and a local machine using rsync over SSH.
Both machines are macs (macOS 10.15.7).

So far I'm using the following command:

```
rsync -av --partial --inplace --progress user@ip:"source/file" "destination/file"
```

The initial sync copies, as expected, the complete file in about 20 minutes.
After changes on the local (eg. destination) file rsync pulls again the complete file (or at least that's what I'm understanding as it still takes 20min to sync).

I could understand for heavy changes in the binary's data, but when I change just few bytes (ex: `echo "test" >> destination/file`) the complete file is synced again.

I'm out of ideas, what do you think?

More info:

- macOS 10.15.7
- The two machines are on the same network and both plugged in via Ethernet cables.
- rsync 2.6.9 protocol version 29 (default macOS version)
- The large binary is the virtual disk of a VM (~130 GB).

Comment: Maybe you mean `echo test >> destination/file`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes! thanks